# How to read appsettings file in app.module in Angular 5?

Tags: json, angular, appsettings

Hi I am developing web application in Angular 5. I am trying to read appsettings.json and use the value in app.module.ts. In app.module.ts inside imports I have following line of code.

```
 AppInsightsModule.forRoot('dfd77fnd-3ba9-43e6-a90f-3e762444938b')
```

In the above code value is hard coded. I have below tag in appsettings.json.

```
 "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "dfd77fnd-3ba9-43e6-a90f-3e762444938b"
  }
```

I want to read from appsettings.json. Below the app.module.ts I can read it. I have created service and inject it. App.module.ts the root file in Angular. Here how can i take the value from appsettings.json? Can someone help me to identify the solution for this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For loading the configuration data before application load you can use angular provided APP_INITIALIZER.

Details at :- https://devblog.dymel.pl/2017/10/17/angular-preload/
              https://www.intertech.com/Blog/angular-4-tutorial-run-code-during-app-initialization/

```
 providers: [
    ConfigProvider, 
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: configProviderFactory, deps: [ConfigProvider], multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

Comment: okay so configProviderFactory contains my data. How can i use it in imports section?

Comment: You can use it anyway like:- lconfigProviderFactory(): Promise<Configuration> {
  return this.http.get<Configuration>(`${this.originUrl}${this.configUrlPath}`)
  .do(result => {
    this.configData = result;
  })
  .toPromise();
}

Comment: you can refer this blog as well :- https://www.intertech.com/Blog/angular-4-tutorial-run-code-during-app-initialization/

Comment: In the Component Constructor inject the Provider like :-                                      constructor(configProvider: ConfigProvider) {
    this.configData = configProvider.getConfigData();
 } and then AppInsightsModule.forRoot(this.configData.ApplicationInsights.InstrumentationKey)